# Calculating a lot of Lat/Lngs to a set of 2000 Lat/Lngs in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gis

I am trying to find the best way to solve the problem below:

### Problem

I have (up to) 100,000 Lat/Lng points in Set A
I have (up to) 2000 Lat/Lng points in Set B

I need to find the nearest neighbour of points in set B to points in Set A.

Once they have been paired - I then need to calculate their distance which will be:
2000 Set A points to 2000 Set B Points.

These points are "in memory" they do not come from a database - they are the result of other calculations done the in the system.

### Current Solution

Using a KDTree implementation in Ruby I can create a KDTree lookup that will match the points I have. I then use a haversine method in Ruby to calculate the distance of the points when they are paired.

KDtree code: [Ruby KDTree Code](https://github.com/MagLev/maglev/blob/master/examples/persistence/kdtree/lib/treekd.rb)
haversine Code: [Haversine Code](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_distance_between_two_points_on_a_globe#Ruby)

### Platform

I am running jruby - with rails as the web framework.

### Issue

Its slow! Like 30 to 40 seconds slow... I think the main bottle neck is in the KDtree, but the point look up takes a long time too (i think). At smaller numbers in Set B its quick but the higher the number of points in Set B it gets a lot quicker.

### The Question

Would anyone think of doing this differently? Is there something I am missing. I think a Java library might be a lot quicker, but how would I implement this, and which one would I use (Not strong in Java - I use Jruby for multithreading ruby code in the JVM)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to persist the information to a database? Because then you can use [GeoKit](http://geokit.rubyforge.org/), which leverages a geo-aware database (MySQL, Postgres > 8.1, etc) so that you can do this:

```
Location.find(:all, :origin =>[37.792,-122.393], :within=>10, :order=>"distance asc")
```

Also, you can find the distance between two points, etc. The response time will be more on par with a DB query, and much faster than what you're seeing.

Comment: I have and I did a test that was quite quick - however I assumed that it would be using the same method anyways? I did this just seeing the distance. Not for the entire problem

Comment: i think putting into a database would slow it down over all though. however I could try... ideally i would like to solve this independent of a database

Comment: Well it relies on indexes of the lat/long fields and uses built-in geometry functions of a geo-aware database. That's why the choices are limited to MySQL and Postgres > 8.1.

Comment: you can use it away from a database i think, i will give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea in my mind. If you round your lat/long's to two decimal places then all the points with-in 1.11 km's will be the same. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) for more details. I'm not 100% sure about it but may be it works for you. Off-course for areas near the pols, this will not work as longitude shrinks there.

To speed up the distance calculation between two lat/long's, you can calculate euclidean distance by using simple distance formula rather than geographical distance. This distance will not be accurate off-course but will speed up your process.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however the only issue is that we need it for 50meter accuracy. So the 1.11 idea wont work - but its interesting. I will look in to the euclidean distance

Comment: Approximate 50 meter accuracy can be achieved by rounding to 0.0005, it will give 55.5 meter accuracy. Please let me know if it really works. :)